# Swift Picker View change row in the second component based on the selection of the first component using core data

Tags: swift, core-data, uipickerview

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    getDataAnswer()
}

func getDataAnswer() {

    // Fetch answers
    let answerFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Answer")
    let answerFilter = questions[AnswerResultPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] // **tell me the error** 
    let answerPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "question == %@", answerFilter)
    answerFetch.predicate = answerPredicate

    do {
        answers = try context.fetch(answerFetch) as! [Answer]

    } catch {}
```

[error that appear on the line marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du8oj.png)

> Hi, I have a picker view (called AnswerResultPickerView) and I want that when the User select a row of the first component (where there are questions) in the second component (where are the answers) the answers are filtered based on the related question. All data are in core Data and there is a one to one relationship from answer to question called "question" and the reverse that is one to many

I attach all the code of the view controller, maybe can be helpful:

```
@IBOutlet weak var AnswerResultPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var WeightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var NameTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func CreateButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.AnswerResultPickerView.delegate = self
    self.AnswerResultPickerView.dataSource = self
}

var questions: [Question] = []
var answers: [Answer] = []
var results: [Result] = []

var data = [[Question](), [Answer](), [Result]()] as [[Any]]

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    getDataAnswer()
    getData()
    AnswerResultPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    let numberOfRowsInComponent0: Int = questions.count
    let numberOfRowsInComponent1: Int = answers.count
    let numberOfRowsInComponent2: Int = results.count
    let returnValue = [numberOfRowsInComponent0, numberOfRowsInComponent1, numberOfRowsInComponent2]

    return returnValue[component]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    var returnValue = [String]()

    switch component {
    case 0:
        returnValue = [questions[row].text!]

    case 1:
        returnValue = [answers[row].text!]

    case 2:
        returnValue = [results[row].tip!]

    default:
        break
    }

    return returnValue[0]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    getDataAnswer()
}

func getDataAnswer() {

    // Fetch answers
    let answerFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Answer")
    let answerFilter = questions[AnswerResultPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] // here where the error appear
    let answerPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "question == %@", answerFilter)
    answerFetch.predicate = answerPredicate

    do {
        answers = try context.fetch(answerFetch) as! [Answer]

    } catch {

    }
}

func getData() {

    // Fetch questions
    let questionFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Question")
    let questionFilter = addNewMe
    let questionPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "me = %@", questionFilter)
    questionFetch.predicate = questionPredicate

    // Fetch results
    let resultFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Result")
    let resultFilter = addNewInterest
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "interest = %@", resultFilter)
    resultFetch.predicate = resultPredicate


    do {
        questions = try context.fetch(questionFetch) as! [Question]
        results = try context.fetch(resultFetch) as! [Result]

    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the entire error  that appears pls ? 
It's maybe an "Index out of array bound". 
What is the size of the "questions" array ?

Comment: Yes it is! in the output terminal appear index out of range, and if you want to see the error click on "error that appear on the line marked" @LastMove